# MySQL Retrieving data from multiple tables using information from another table?

Tags: mysql, reference

QUESTION: How do you use a conditional statement in MySQL to retrieve data in two other tables?

Comment: You could read about joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieving both the name and the salary can be done with a `join`.
Finding only the supervisors of janitors could also theoretically be done with a `join`, but assuming that a city worker may supervise more than one janitor, the `in` operator would be better suited:

```
SELECT Name, Salary
FROM   Citizen c
JOIN   CityWorker cw ON c.SSN = cw.CityID
WHERE  cw.CityID IN (SELECT SupervisorID 
                     FROM   Employee
                     WHERE  Job = 'Janitor')
```